# Notification is not working in Release mode after enabling proguard and minification

Tags: android, notifications, proguard

My notifications are working fine in debug mode. But I am not getting any notifications for release/signed apk whenever minifyenabled is true. I  have added all the possible solutions . Added firebase rules too. Below is my proguard rule file. My Android studio version 3.4.2 and firebase messaging version is 19.0.1

**proguard-rules.pro**

```
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
#remove logs
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log{
  public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
  public static int v(...);
  public static int i(...);
  public static int w(...);
  public static int d(...);
  public static int e(...);
  public static int wtf(...);
}

#Eventbus
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
}
-keep enum org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode { *; }

# Only required if you use AsyncExecutor
-keepclassmembers class * extends org.greenrobot.eventbus.util.ThrowableFailureEvent {
    <init>(java.lang.Throwable);
}

#Retrofit
# Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-keepattributes Exceptions

# OkHttp
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-keepnames class okhttp3.internal.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixDatabase

# OkHttp platform used only on JVM and when Conscrypt dependency is available.
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform

# Proguard Configuration for Realm (http://realm.io)
# For detailed discussion see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/realm-java/umqKCc50JGU
# Additionally you need to keep your Realm Model classes as well
# For example:

-keepattributes directive
#Glide
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}
# Uncomment for DexGuard only
#-keepresourcexmlelements manifest/application/meta-data@value=GlideModule


##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes InnerClasses
# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
#dagger 2
-dontwarn com.google.errorprone.annotations.**

#kotlin
-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }
-keepclassmembers public class com.mypackage.** {
    public synthetic <methods>;
}
-keep class kotlinx.android.synthetic.**
-keepclassmembers class android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView {
    boolean mShiftingMode;
}

#Realm
-keep @interface io.realm.annotations.RealmModule { *; }
-keep class io.realm.annotations.RealmModule { *; }


# please KEEP ALL THE NAMES
-keepnames class ** { *; }
-keep class com.mypackage.model.** { *; }

-keepclassmembers public class com.mypackage.** {
    public synthetic <methods>;
}
#FCM
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }

-keepclassmembers class com.mypackage.model.** { *;}
-ignorewarnings

-dontwarn

# JSR 305 annotations are for embedding nullability information.
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**



# Animal Sniffer compileOnly dependency to ensure APIs are compatible with older versions of Java.
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.*

-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }

-keep class android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat { *; }

-keep class android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$* { *; }

-keep class android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat { *; }

-dontnote com.google.**
```

Comment: Have you given SHA or without it ?

Comment: @Piyush I have added sha in firebase account

Comment: Then you have to add SHA as a release . When u used it it was for debug mode

Comment: @Piyush I am generating debug and release version with the same keystore. And google sign in  is working propelry for both debug and release version. Only notifications are not working

Comment: Are you testing on the same device?

Comment: If notifications are not working then have you checked from Firebase console for test send notification? Install your app from play store and send notification from Firebase and check it

Comment: @Piyush When I sent notification from console, I received it on debug version but not on release version

Comment: Then it's a release SHA issue. And also without SHA we can generate json file. Because it's a optional.

Comment: @Bek No. Both devices have different tokens

Comment: Have you set notification channel? Starting from android 8 you must create notification channel.

Comment: @Bek Yes. I have created notification channel for oreo and above and getting notification for the same in debug apk

Comment: If you did everything then it is the issue of SHA.  Just put break point and check that notification class calls or not?